# Range Copy from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm new on vba and I'm trying to copy the values from a different sheet, the data is a part of a colum so I get the column number from the original sheet with a match and the row number froma count function.

when i run the code

```
Dim numDatos As Integer
Dim numCol As Integer
Dim datosCopiar As Range
    
    numDatos = Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  
    numCol = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(fecha)), Worksheets("W1").Range("BG9:CV9"), 0) 
    datosCopiar = Range(Worksheets("W1").Cells(11, numCol), Worksheets("W1").Cells(numDatos, numCol))
    datosCopiar.Copy Worksheets("final").Range("M3")
```

> Runtime Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

in the range definition line

"final" is the active sheet and "W1" is the datasheet

Comment: Note that one needs `Set` for a `Range` variable: `Set datosCopiar = ...`. Also it's a lot easier to use `With Worksheets("W1")`, `Set datosCopiar = .Range(.Cells(11, numCol), .Cells(numDatos, numCol))`, `End With`.

Comment: But your error will probably come from the fact that the `Application.Match` is not finding a match and you are passing an error as the column number.

Comment: Instead of `numCol` in the to be `Set datosCopiar` line you need to use `Worksheets("W1").Range("BG9:CV9").Columns(NumCol).Column`. `NumCol` is the 'n-th' column of the row range `BG9:CV9`, not of the worksheet. All these long expressions can be avoided by using variables for workbooks, worksheets, ranges, and whatnot. That's what they are used for.